# ios webview - how to check notifications when the app is not running

Tags: c#, iphone, ios, ajax, notifications

For my app, I'm using a webview. I have implemented the notifications by following this tutorial :

http://www.raywenderlich.com/32960/apple-push-notification-services-in-ios-6-tutorial-part-1

In my website I use a js code that check new event added in the db:

```
function checkNotification() 
{
  $.ajax({
           url: '/checkNewMessages',
           type: "GET",
           success: function (result) 
           {
              // if new event, then I run the #c code below to tell
              // the APN server to send the notif to the device.
           }
         });
}
```

To send the notifications I'm using a #c code:

```
var deviceToken = "2191a536a52445046797a871fe3c4cf...";
var message = "this is a notification.";
var badge = 1;
var password = "blablabla";
var payload = new NotificationPayload(deviceToken, message, badge);
var notificationList = new List<NotificationPayload>() { payload };
var push = new PushNotification(true, "apn_developer_identity.p12", password);
var result = push.SendToApple(notificationList);
```

And I check this every 10000 milisec

```
setInterval(checkNotification, 10000);
```

But this js code will be running only when the user is on the app. What's happen when the app is not running ? The user won't be able to receive the notifications ? I need a script always running in background checking new event on my db. What is the best way to do this ? Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Push notification are handled by iOS not your app, thus when your server send a push notification to an users app they will just receive it.

Only when you the user opens the app using the notification is it possible to detect the notification used to open the app. You check for the notification used to open the on the

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions {
   NSDictionary *remoteNotif =[launchOptions objectForKey:UIApplicationLaunchOptionsRemoteNotificationKey];
    if (remoteNotif) {
       /* handle the notification.
    }
}
```

There is not way to monitor push notification in the background.

Comment: So the only solution is to run a script on my server, that check new event added to the db ? I cannot use a js code ? Thanks for your help

Comment: No, since the all webview are unloaded when your app goes in the background. Push notification are designed to be server side to save battery and also bring down network traffic.

Comment: I see, makes sense. Do have any idea how to do this using asp .net ? I mean I already have the #c code ready to send notifications, but I don't know when to call it...

Comment: ASP.net is for website, push notification only work for native apps, there are no push notifications in for web based app. If you are using  Xamarin have a look in there documentation. It should be in het some where.